# LazyLoad a custom CSS Masonry Grid

Tags: javascript, css, lazy-loading

I have created a very simple CSS grid, with 3 columns, and display images within those columns.  The images are set in a data-src, as I am trying to lazy load them in.

I am trying to use the lazyload.js file here:

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vanilla-lazyload@12.0.0/dist/lazyload.min.js

I'm happy to change the lazyload JS file if I need to use a diff one.

I have 2 issues: Firstly, as the images are loading in, they are 'jumping' around, as it loads an image and shuffles the others around. (on my live site, doesn't seem to happen on Codepen).

Secondly, the lazy load doesn't seem to be working.  I want it to load them in as the user scrolls down, maybe even fading them in, but instead it seems to just load everything all at once.

For the first issue,: I suspect I need to set some sort of placeholder to make sure the image is 'placed' in the grid immediately, even though it only loads on scroll via the data-src.  I tried adding a blank.gif in the src, and setting the width/height of the image in the img tag.  This doesn't seem to work.

For the second: I can't seem to work out why it's not working.

Here's my codepen:

```
<div class="gallery-holder">
   <section id="photos">
   <img src="blank.gif" class="lazy" data-src="https://smokymtnriverrat.com/rafting/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2019/02/home-heaer.jpg" height="1000" width="1500">

<img src="blank.gif" class="lazy" data-src="https://smokymtnriverrat.com/rafting/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2018/02/contact.jpg" height="600" width="1900" >

<img src="blank.gif" class="lazy" data-src="https://smokymtnriverrat.com/rafting/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2017/03/IMG_2336-1.jpg" height="2056" width="3088" >

<img src="blank.gif" class="lazy" data-src="https://smokymtnriverrat.com/rafting/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2018/02/IMG_2299.jpg" height="2056" width="3088">

<img src="blank.gif" class="lazy" data-src="https://smokymtnriverrat.com/rafting/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2018/02/rafters.jpg" height="545" width="1900" >

<img src="blank.gif" class="lazy" data-src="https://smokymtnriverrat.com/rafting/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2018/02/retail1.jpg" height="410" width="795">

<img src="blank.gif" class="lazy" data-src="https://smokymtnriverrat.com/rafting/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2018/02/retail4.jpg" height="410" width="795" >

<img src="blank.gif" class="lazy" data-src="https://smokymtnriverrat.com/rafting/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2018/02/wwr_retail.jpg" height="410" width="795">

<img src="blank.gif" class="lazy" data-src="https://smokymtnriverrat.com/rafting/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2017/03/lower_pigeon.jpg" height="410" width="795">

<img src="blank.gif" class="lazy" data-src="https://smokymtnriverrat.com/rafting/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2017/03/upper_pigeon.jpg" height="410" width="795">

<img src="blank.gif" class="lazy" data-src="https://smokymtnriverrat.com/rafting/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2017/03/extreme_upper.jpg" height="410" width="795">

  </section>
</div>

<style>
#photos {
   /* Prevent vertical gaps */
   line-height: 30px;

   -webkit-column-count: 3;
   -webkit-column-gap:   10px;
   -moz-column-count:    3;
   -moz-column-gap:      10px;
   column-count:         3;
   column-gap:           10px;
}

#photos img {
  /* Just in case there are inline attributes */
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto !important;
}
.gallery-holder {
    display: block;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  #photos {
  -moz-column-count:    2;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  column-count:         2;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
.gallery-holder { 
    width:100%;
    padding:0 20px;
}
  #photos {
  -moz-column-count:    1;
  -webkit-column-count: 1;
  column-count:         1;
  }
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
var lazyLoadInstance = new LazyLoad({
elements_selector: ".lazy"
// ... more custom settings?
});
</script>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XwXRBG

Comment: Did you read the documentation? i found another script, which has to be implemented: 

To be sure that DOM for your lazy content is ready when you instantiate LazyLoad, place the script tag right before the closing </body> tag. If more DOM arrives later, e.g. via an AJAX call, you'll need to call lazyLoadInstance.update(); to make LazyLoad check the DOM again.

if (lazyLoadInstance) {
    lazyLoadInstance.update();
}

Comment: The images are already in the DOM in the codepen?

Comment: i dont know how codepen works, but it seems like the images are allready there